# Unable to start azure application in dev fabric

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage

Suddenly my windows azure application is stopped running in dev fabric. It was working fine.  When I added two project "AspProviders" and "StorageClient" in my solution then, its not running. It is not firing any events also. There is no error but not not running.

Output has the following message:

```
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CppCodeProvider\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\CppCodeProvider.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\dftmp\s0\deployment(1033)\res\deployment(1033).myDoxii_Azure.myDoxii_WebRole.0\aspNetTemp\aspNetTemp\root\d81afa8a\20b8682\assembly\dl3\797cae85\052a6b99_161ccb01\DataAccessLayer.DLL', Symbols loaded.
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\dftmp\s0\deployment(1033)\res\deployment(1033).myDoxii_Azure.myDoxii_WebRole.0\aspNetTemp\aspNetTemp\root\d81afa8a\20b8682\assembly\dl3\91a891b3\009963f2_74a2ca01\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DLL'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\dftmp\s0\deployment(1033)\res\deployment(1033).myDoxii_Azure.myDoxii_WebRole.0\aspNetTemp\aspNetTemp\root\d81afa8a\20b8682\assembly\dl3\e6e4830f\00c694f3_74a2ca01\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.DLL'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\dftmp\s0\deployment(1033)\res\deployment(1033).myDoxii_Azure.myDoxii_WebRole.0\aspNetTemp\aspNetTemp\root\d81afa8a\20b8682\assembly\dl3\10d71fa9\234dc4ed_1e1ccb01\myDoxii_WebRole.DLL', Symbols loaded.
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\dftmp\s0\deployment(1033)\res\deployment(1033).myDoxii_Azure.myDoxii_WebRole.0\aspNetTemp\aspNetTemp\root\d81afa8a\20b8682\assembly\dl3\80db026d\008829c9_96dbca01\Telerik.Web.UI.DLL'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\dftmp\s0\deployment(1033)\res\deployment(1033).myDoxii_Azure.myDoxii_WebRole.0\aspNetTemp\aspNetTemp\root\d81afa8a\20b8682\assembly\dl3\ccfba1fa\3f7c9899_161ccb01\WebService.DLL', Symbols loaded.
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Design\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Design.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Speech\3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Speech.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.Runtime\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.Runtime.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\msshrtmi\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\msshrtmi.dll'
'WaWebHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll'
The program '[6232] WaWebHost.exe: Managed' has exited with code -532459699 (0xe0434f4d).
```

And Shown Development Fabric UI :

```
fabric] Role Instance: deployment(1024).myDoxii_Azure.myDoxii_WebRole.0

[fabric] Role state Busy

[fabric] Role state Stopping

[fabric] Role state Stopped

[fabric] Role state Aborted

[fabric] Role state Teardown

[fabric] Role state Destroyed

[fabric] Role state Created

[fabric] Role state Suspended
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

0xe0434f4d means that it is an exception from the CLR (ie any managed exception is referred to with this code).

In my experience such error is (most of the times) accompanied by:

> Could not load file or assembly 'XXXX' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

This could be caused by **missing dependency** (or invalid one). You need to make sure that your Roles have "Copy Local" set to true for all non-GAC assembly references.